# I want to datetime picker in a single view?

Tags: android, datetimepicker

I'm developing android application.In that i want to pick a date and time in a single selection.i.e date and time picker in the same view. I have used third party date time picker but that does not look good. So please suggest me is there is any datetime picker available..?
Please give me a example code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
   TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
     new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view,
                    int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    ///Select Date and time
         };
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
        return new TimePickerDialog(this,
                mTimeSetListener, mHour, mMinute, false);
    }
    return null;
}
```

It will give you selection of date